# Как работает alarm в модулях RTC(Real Time Clock)?

Tags: arduino

В наличии имеется модуль RTC DS3234(SPI) + Arduino.
Общая Задача: настроить аларм на rtc и по аларму заставить срабатывать реле, которое будет включать ардуино, ардуино делает что надо и выключается и так 3 раза в день.
Но самое главное понять, как вообще работают алармы в модулях rtc, на сколько я понял при срабатывании аларма, данный rtc выдает пульс 5 вольт.

Answer (score 3):

В DS3234 можно установить два времени срабатывания будильника. Оба будильника могут срабатывать каждую минуту, каждый час. Оба будильника можно установить на срабатывание в заданное время и дату, либо в заданное время дня недели.
Будильник 1 может срабатывать каждую секунду.
При срабатывании будильника устанавливается в 1 бит A1F (A2F для будильника 2).
Чтобы по будильнику 1 сработал сигнал ~INT/SQW, следует установить в 1 бит A1IE (A2IE для будильника 2). Название сигнала ~INT означает, что по прерыванию установится значение 0. Чтобы сбросить его в 1, нужно записать 0 в бит A1F (A2F).